# What options are available for mapping a database schema?

Tags: macos, schema

What are some programs that people use to map out a database schema with several tables and inter-connected keys?  Preferably for OS X.

Comment: There are some great tools... depends on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) is a semi-decent tool (especially if you're using MySQL), although I haven't tried the OSX version. They're busy upgrading to version 5.2 at the moment, which looks like it will be a lot better than the current stable 5.1 version.  Still kind of buggy though, so 5.1 is the way to go unless you're brave.